# Set priority on a firebase transaction (node JavaScript)

Tags: node.js, transactions, firebase

Is there a way to set priority in a transaction in firebase? I'm creating a system for voting on things using node, and I'm using a function like this to prevent collisions when users simultaneously vote:

```
update.resource.total.transaction(function(c) { return c + 1; });
```

- `update` is a collection of firebase reference URLs
- `total` is a property of the objects `vote` child, and is just a counter.

It would be great if I could also set priority here so that objects are returned in order of popularity. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the priority and the value in the transaction. [For example](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/jYF48/):

```
firebaseRef.transaction(function(currentValue) {
   return { '.value': currentValue + 1, '.priority': newPriority };
}, function(err, committed, snap) {
   /* process results */
});
```

Comment: This is awesome! I can't seem to find it anywhere in the docs though. Hoping this behavior doesn't disappear one day!

Comment: If it does, it will be replaced by something better. Since the SDK's are versioned, you'll decide when you upgrade.

Comment: Great. There was a post a while back about .priority being a little finnicky. Any idea if that's still the case? This method seems to be working fine for me so far :)

Comment: There was a bug when using priority with transaction(); that was corrected afaik. It works wonderfully with set. I think it does not work with update() by design.